# Arabic and English text together in same label or in alert message

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, arabic-support, uialertviewcontroller

I am getting message from backend which contain both Arabic string as well as englist string when i set that message on alert it looks same as attached SS.
original message = "+966897845123 أدخل كلمة المرور لمرة واحدة (OTP) التي تم إرسالها"
[Actual Result when set to alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyx4r.png)

I'm expecting exact same string in UI also..How can i set this string for proper result.

Tried some stack overflow solution but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this when setting the string to UILabel

```
yourLabel.text = "\u{202A}+966897845123 أدخل كلمة المرور لمرة واحدة (OTP) التي تم إرسالها\u{202A}"
```